# VBA to chart multiple named ranges on different tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I have a chart which is updated via a VBA macro assigned to a developer button:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Tab1").Range("Range1")
```

The VBA references a named range (Range1) which uses OFFSET logic to reference the range of data needed, in the floowing way.

```
=OFFSET('data sheet'!$A$6,0,0, COUNTIF('data sheet'!$A$7:$A$506,">1")+1,COUNTIF('data sheet'!$A$3:$GT$3,"*"))
```

I now have need to add in more series to this chart and would like to add Range 2 to my chart but find that amending my VBA to the following is not working:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Union(Sheets("Tab1").Range("Range1"),Sheets("Tab2").Range("Range2"))
```

ps, I have not included an example dataset here as all parts othe process use dynamic named ranges so a solution built on any nXn data grid should work here as long as variables are stored in column form

Comment: Can you try to add more sources with macrorecorder and see what is it producing?

Comment: Hi, the recorder doesn't use the .SetSourceData syntax. It produces: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(23).Name = "='Tab2"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(23).Values = _
        "='Tab2'!$B$7:$B$201"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add [Range2]
```

Comment: I know this wasn't part of the original question but if my range includes column headers is there a line of VBA i can add to: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add [Range2]` so that row 1 is used as a column header than what excel is currently doing in adding it as part of the series?

Comment: The above line returns a Series object, and you can modify its properties. You can either write Dim s As Series: Set s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add([Range2]) s.Property... or With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add([Range2]) .Property... End With. I think you need ApplyDataLabels. You can look up these properties and methods in the VBA Editor by hitting F2. The exact code depends on the exact layout of the Sheet.

Comment: Well, SeriesCollection.Add has a parameter for labels, so you can write something like ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=[Range2] SeriesLabels:=[Range3].

Comment: I've treid all of the above and no joy. I set Range1 to the original range but not including the row with the column headers and then created Range2 as just the column headers and ran `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add [Range], SeriesLabels:=[Range]` but nothing happened???

Comment: Meant to say `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Add [Range1], SeriesLabels:=[Range2]`

Comment: As I see, you mixed the two Ranges and are missing the Source:= part.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=" & [my_range].Name
```

Instead of a union.
[my_range] should be Range2 in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Vityata - how do I add the tab2 element in?... or do I not need to? Range2 sits in and refers to tab2 data

Comment: Just try without the tab2 element. "Range2" should take care about it.

Comment: `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=" & Range2.Name` gives me a "Object required" error and     `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=" & "Range2"` gives me an "application/object-defined error"

Comment: ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=" & [Range2].Name

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise I had to include the square brackets. It's still giving an application/object-defined error

Comment: Try with Address instead of Name.